# How to add library Android studio 0.2.11

Tags: java, android, jar

My android studio is update and I am not adding a jar library.

1. I'm adding a new directory, libs name.
2. My jar file copy and paste in libs file.
3. Right click jar file and add library.
4. add code build.gradle file compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
5. I click project structure but i dont see library tab (as the picture)

   [http://www.tjod.org/questions/project-error.png](http://www.medyasef.com/questions/project-error.png)

My project give this error

```
 10-05 17:58:36.070  13129-13129/com.medyasef.delirium
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
             at com.medyasef.delirium.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygote
```

Please help me.
Sorry bad english. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti http://www.medyasef.com/questions/build_gradle.png

Comment: It seems ok. Are you sure that gradle builds your project successfully?
You can also use this script in your build.gradle.
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

Comment: I dont sure  gradle builds your project successfully, because this morning update android studio and everything corrupted., I try your script but not fixed. http://www.medyasef.com/questions/script.png

Comment: If it doesn't build your project, check for gradle errors. The problem is in another part.